# C++: Reading a character is incorrect

Tags: c++, char, hex, scanf

Getting a weird problem trying to read chars from a text file in C++.  When it finds an apostrophe (hex 92) it reads it as multiple characters.  For the string "it’s" I get this:

```
i - 69
t - 74
’ - ffffff92
s - 73
it’s
```

Here's the code:

```
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("word.txt", "rb");
    char buf[111];

    fscanf(fp, "%s", buf);

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(buf);   ++i)
        printf("%c - %x\n", buf[i], buf[i]);

    printf(buf);
}
```

Opening as "r" gives the same result.  How can I read the apostrophe as the single char that it is?  Thanks!

Comment: This looks more like C. Is this C?

Comment: It's C++, but it would also compile in C.  I get the same result using a stream.

Comment: If `char` is signed (likely), it will get sign extended when promoted to an `int` in a variadic function. Printing a signed value as unsigned could result in unexpected output.

Comment: Note that 0x92 is not a canonical apostrophe. That would be 0x27 (Unicode U+0027 APOSTROPHE) instead. 0x92 is outside of the ASCII range, so it is subject to charset interpretation. 0x92 is Unicode U+2019 RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK in Windows-1252, for instance, but is different/undefined in other charsets. When dealing with 8bit text data, charsets matter.

Comment: Thanks Bo Persson; using an unsigned char array seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cast buf[i] to unsigned char - character is read correctly - but when printing - since it is negative - it is extended to int and then cased to unsigned int so you see ffffff92 - casting to unsigned should display the value correctly

```
#include<cstdio>

int main() {

    char ch = static_cast<char>(0x92);
    printf("%c - %x/%x\n", ch,ch,static_cast<unsigned char>(ch));

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
$ ./test
� - ffffff92/92
```

Comment: @UserX  What is your compiler - since I got the predicted output with gcc 5.4